# Getting C# object reference in Unity3D

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, inventory

I want to get C# object in unity by clicking on it. I made ray and it works properly. Problem is in copying object. I'm making something like inventory system. All of my collectable items have item scripts with variables like name or ID. For getting C# object of script from gameobject I'm using

```
itemList.Add (hitInfo.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Item> ()); // adding C# object to C# List
```

and then I destroy gameobject (maybe it's a problem), but when i try print something like itemList[0].name it's not work because of: "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"
It's caused by destroing object? Or I should just copy reference of the object in other way (by not using `itemList.Add (hitInfo.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Item> ())`)?

EDIT://Exception appearce even if I don't destroy the gameobject.
EDIT2://When I start game and check itemList.Count; (it should show the number of elements in the list I think) it's 15 not 0 and I don't know why.

Comment: Could you provide more code, where you define the list, and where is the call that leads to the `NullReferenceException`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding, the code you posted is getting the "Item" component from the object you click on. A component instance MUST have a single object that it is associated with. So when you delete the object, you are also deleting the "Item" component on that object.

What you should really do is have a data model class for the item as a Field on the component. This class would contain whatever data (name, is required by your inventory. So instead of adding the Item component to the list you would add the data model. The reference to this model class will persist when the GameObject is deleted.

```
public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    [System.Serializable]
    public ItemModel Model;
}

public class ItemModel
{
    public string Name;
    public int Id;
}
```

Get it like this:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Item>().Model
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work but in class:
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Item : MonoBehaviour {
 [System.Serializable]
 public ItemModel model;
}
I have the error: The attribute `System.SerializableAttribute' is not valid on this declaration type. It is valid on `class, struct, enum, delegate' declarations only

I know I did something wrong, but I don't know what.
I have ItemModel and Item in seperate scripts.

Comment: Ok I removed [System.Serializable] and it's wrok great thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from what I can tell the problem is because you are destroying the object after you add it to the list.

I am assuming, what you want is for the player to 'pick up' an object from the world and add it to an inventory.

There are many different ways to achieve this, and the best solution will depend on how you need your inventory to work.

A simple way to achieve an inventory is to have a Dictionary< string, int> where the string is the name of the item and the int is the number held.

Comment: not a problem. As said, there are many ways to achieve an inventory and the best way will really depend on how you need your inventory to work.

The main advantage of the method I suggest is that you can save memory (and potentially CPU work) by simply storing a string/int combination rather than the actual object.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is instead of destroying the object, you could deactivate it with
 `hitInfo.transform.gameObject.SetActive(False)` . When you need the object in the game you can reactivate it at a desired location, or retrieve only the required info from the  `Item`  script, like the name, member variables (strengthOfAttack, healingPoints) or the sprite texture or model or whatever.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to do something like hitInfo.transform.gameObject.enabled but it didn't work and your solution work. If destroing object will causes errors when I will drop items from inventory I will use this way. Thanks one more time :)

Comment: glad  I could be of any assistance :)